# iOS - UITextField being squashed by UILabel

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uitextfield, uilabel

I have an issue where what is being shown in IB is not actually what is appearing in the simulator.  Please see the following screen captures:

[image]

As you can see it is a simple UITableViewCell, containing a label and a text field, (the grey background is demonstrate it being there).

This is how it appears in the simulator:

[image]

As you can see, the label is completely squashing the textfield to the end of the cell.  What could be causing this?  My code is as follows:

```
[[(MyCustomCell *)cell textLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"email"]];
```

The cell is just created using loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass.  I do not add any other fields to the cell programmatically.  The only dynamic part is the actual label renaming.

Any ideas welcome, cheers!

UPDATE:

When I select the field, this occurs:

[image]

Or if I long press the field, a magnifying glass appears and I can see the text in the text field.  This is really peculiar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised my mistake - pretty stupid really!

I was accessing the iOS property `textLabel`, instead of my `IBOutlet textField`.  Another autocomplete mistake!

Answer (score 1):

My guess: the Autosizing was not set correct for both the Label and the Textfield. Check it in IB, where you set the frame size for an element, beyond is the autosizing.

Comment: What should be setting these options to? I don't really understand the autosizing configuration in IB.  I've updated my question with another screenshot of what happens.